# Before update oracle trigger problem [PL/SQL]

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE1 (column1 integer, column2 integer, column3 integer);
```

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE1 VALUES (1,11,111);
```

Trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE UPDATE OF COLUMN1 ON EXAMPLE1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'You can't directly update this column.');
END;
```

Update:

```
UPDATE EXAMPLE1 SET COLUMN1 = 2 WHERE COLUMN2 = 11;
```

So, when I try to update the column1 (column1 = 2) trigger should execute and tell me that I can't directly change that column, but if I execute a query like this:

```
UPDATE EXAMPLE1 SET column1 = 1, column2 = 22 where column3 = 111;
```

I mean where I send also column1 = 1 (column1 is equal to 1) so there is no changing of value, it should update the table because I'm changing just column2, column1 stays unchanged equal to 1.

Comment: you are still updating the column no matter what the new value is , in your trigger you have to check if the value is changing or not

Comment: @eshirvana is there any chance to send me a code of how it should be, I'm new to this :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are still updating the column no matter what the new value is , in your trigger you have to check if the value is changing or not :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE UPDATE OF COLUMN1 ON EXAMPLE1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF DECODE(:new.column1, :old.column1, 1, 0) = 0 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'You can''t directly update this column.')
    END IF
END;
```

Comment: You need to handle `null` also - what if one of the values (either old or new), or both, is/are `null`?

Comment: Err... the `nvl` approach is common, but wrong. What if the new value is 1 but the old value was `null`? Your condition will allow the update, since it sees `null` the same as 1. You could modify that so that instead of 1 you use a different value (one that is not possible in the data), but even that is a poor practice. The more common way to write it is `if decode(:new.column1, :old.column1, 1, 0) = 0 then...` - `decode` is often used because it considers `null` as equal to `null` (similar to what you have in `group by` for example, and different from most other SQL).

Comment: Nah, still have a problem I tried, and if I update all other columns it will update, but if I change the restricted column it won't give me a back message from raise_application. That column is a foreign key btw (used short-circuit key) so that column is updating from other table, but from this its restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `when` clause as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE UPDATE OF COLUMN1 ON EXAMPLE1
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ( NEW.COLUMN1 <> OLD.COLUMN1 
       OR NOT (NEW.COLUMN1 IS NULL AND OLD.COLUMN1 IS NULL)
      ) 
BEGIN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'You can''t directly update this column.');
END;
/
```